# Compare multiple columns that can be NULL

Tags: sql, logic, teradata

I want to compare a set of columns and decide:

1. If all columns that is not NULL are equal
2. If any columns that is not NULL are unequal
3. If all columns are NULL

Example input and output:

```
Inn: 'NO', NULL, 'GB', 'NO', 'NO'
Out: 1) FALSE; 2) TRUE; 3) FALSE
----
Inn: 'NO', NULL, 'NO', 'NO', 'NO'
Out: 1) TRUE; 2) FALSE; 3) FALSE
----
Inn: NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
Out: 1) FALSE; 2) FALSE; 3) TRUE
```

The number of columns i need to test is quite a few so the logical statements to compare each an every one is a bit cumbersome.

System: Teradata SQL database

Comment: You want to check each column result, row by row? Maybe you can use a case statement in order to make it work?

Comment: Since you have (as suggested) a relatively large number of columns, I would attempt to pivot each record into a single-column table and perform operations on it. Yes, this might become _expensive_if your original table has millions of records, but the alternative of building a `CASE` structure will take away your sleep. I would think many times before going into that.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `case` expression.  Perhaps:

```
select (case when a is null and b is null and c is null and d is null
             then 'all null'
             when coalesce(a, b, c, d) = coalesce(b, c, d, a) and
                  coalesce(a, b, c, d) = coalesce(c, d, b, a) and
                  coalesce(a, b, c, d) = coalesce(d, a, b, c)
             then 'all non-nulls are equal'
             else 'unequal'
         end);
```

Comment: I don't understand your second test (with the coalesces). If any of a,b,c,and d are null, coalescing them will result in a null.  I'm thinking this is for checking that any non-nulls match, but won't this test only work if all 4 are not null?

Comment: @Andrew . . . Au contraire.  If any of the a, b, c, d are *not* null, then coalescing will be not null.  The `coalesce()` would only be null if *all* were null.

Comment: Oh my, somehow I managed to see and write `coalesce` but think `concat`.  Must be time for a vacation...